# Keeping values for first level of month in a data frame while set rest of the values to zero in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, zero

I have the following data set;

```
df <- matrix(data = c("G1", "March", 98.97291, 
                      "G1", "April", 95.99673,
                      "G2", "January", 97.46496,
                      "G2", "February", 100.56501,
                      "G2", "March", 99.43287, 
                      "G2", "April", 103.00277,
                      "G2", "November", 98.11647, 
                      "G2", "December", 101.56892),
             nrow = 8, ncol = 3, byrow = T
)

df <- as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df) <- c("group", "month", "values")
df$values <- as.numeric(df$values)
```

The output of the df object is given below:

```
   group   month  values
1    G1    March  98.97291
2    G1    April  95.99673
3    G2  January  97.46496
4    G2 February 100.56501
5    G2    March  99.43287
6    G2    April 103.00277
7    G2 November  98.11647
8    G2 December 101.56892
```

I wants to keep values for each group `G1` and `G2` only for first level of the month. For example in `G1` for the month `March` and in `G2` for the month `January` the values should remain in the data frame while I want to set rest of the values to zero.

I would be thankful for your help in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ifelse` + `row_number`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(values = ifelse(row_number() == 1, values, 0))
```

output

```r
  group month    values
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 G1    March      99.0
2 G1    April       0  
3 G2    January    97.5
4 G2    February    0  
5 G2    March       0  
6 G2    April       0  
7 G2    November    0  
8 G2    December    0
```

Also works with `replace`:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(values = replace(values, row_number() != 1, 0))
```

Comment: Will that work if there are repeated values? e.g. if G2/March is also 97.46496?

Comment: Good point. Now it'll. See edit

Comment: I just added an answer in case there are repeated first months with different values, e.g. G2/January/97.5 and G2/January/94.5, and you want to keep both

Comment: I'm grateful. The results are exactly what I needed, and I'll continue to utilise this table in a barplot by just displaying the bars for the months that have any value and hiding the other bars with a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions from Maël already work fine, here's just another way using `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  mutate(values = case_when(
    month == first(month) ~ values,
    TRUE ~ 0
  ))
```

Comment: I am also grateful for this alternative command to get the same output. Thank you